# Can't start MongoDB service [Error: 1067] || "msg":"*** immediate exit due to unhandled exception" || version : 7.0.4

Tags: installation, mongodb

After failing multiple times with many hours of hopeless fixing I simply typed "mongod" command in CMD:Admin and got this error. I'm attaching the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't start MongoDB service \[Error: 1067\] || "msg":"\*\*\* immediate exit due to unhandled exception" || version : 7.0.4](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/36645/cant-start-mongodb-service-error-1067-msg-immediate-exit-due-to-un)

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Did you try to start the mongod more than once?